# shell script while loop trigger build

Tags: linux, shell, while-loop

I have a requirement to trigger a build for some specific projects, which are seperated in a text file with comma.

I wrote a shell script to split the contents of the file, extract the folder and navigate to that folder. Once navigation is done, trigger a build and this should happen for all project paths. The below script works fine if i do listing files in directory after navigation, but while doing a gradle build this executes only once.

Below is my shell script

```
CWD="$(pwd)"
INPUT=deploy.txt
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read f1
do
  echo "$f1 building...";
  (
    cd $f1;
    gradle clean b u;
    cd $CWD;

   )
  echo "Build over"

done <  $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Any issue with this script? Please help

Comment: Does `gradle` read from standard input? If so, it may be consuming the rest of the input file before the next time `read f1` is executed.

Comment: But neither the loop is executing or printing the second iteration. It is printing if I do ls -ltr instead of gradle build.

Comment: That's because the second time `read f1` executes, there is no more input to read (assuming `gradle` has read it all), and so the loop exits after the first iteration. `ls` does *not* read from standard input.

Comment: Thank you @chepner.  I was trying to run gradle inside a bash while loop and redirecting standard input fixed it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is speculative (redirecting standard input for the `gradle` command), but I wanted to take the opportunity to fix some other problems with your script.

```
INPUT=deploy.txt
# Consider exiting with status 1 instead of 99 unless you have
# a specific reason for using 99.
[ ! -f "$INPUT" ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while IFS=, read -r f1 rest
do
  echo "$f1 building..."
  pushd "$f1"
  gradle clean b u < /dev/null
  popd

  echo "Build over"

done < "$INPUT"
```

I assume you are changing the value of `IFS` in order to split the line read from `$INPUT`; in that case, you need to give `read` at least two variables so that the first field is assigned to `f1` and the rest of the line is assigned to another variable. Using `pushd` and `popd` together is simpler than manually recording the old working directory; since you were using a subshell, you didn't need to use `CWD` anyway because the effect of the first `cd` was only in effect until that subshell exited anyway.

---

If, for whatever reason, `gradle` *does* need access to standard input, use a different file descriptor to read from `$INPUT`. (You might consider doing this anyway; you absolutely *know* that `read` is supposed to read from `$INPUT`, so there's no reason to interfere with `gradle` at all.)

```
while IFS=, read -r f1 rest <&3; do
  echo "$f1 building..."
  pushd "$f1"
  gradle clean b u
  popd
done 3< "$INPUT"
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved the issue. What you explained is correct. gradle doesnt need access to standard input. Also needs a second variable